# M.2 SDD drive doesn't appear on Boot Order but it appears on Linux

Tags: boot, bios, m.2

I have installed a 970 EVO Plus NVMe M.2 SDD drive with 500GB on my GA-Z97X-Gaming 7 (rev. 1.0) motherboard.

This unit doesn't appear on the BIOS and either on the boot order list, but I can find it with Linux using the command: "lsblk -o KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL". And I have also installed Windows 10 on it. I have checked after Windows 10 installation that this units appears as a drive on Linux.

But when I try to select this drive as the first drive to boot, it doesn't appear.

How can I select this M.2 drive to boot from it?

BIOS version is F6.

BIOS date: 05/30/2014

BIOS identifier: 8A06AG0I

SSD: V-NAND SSD 970 EVO Plus MVME M.2. Model: MZ-V7S500. Model Code: MZ-V7S500BW.

Comment: That is not unusual for an older system. It means that your BIOS is not able to boot from NVMe drives. Linux and other OS have their own drivers for accessing NVMe drives and thus can access them no matter if the BIOS can do so or not.

Comment: (Re-)install a UEFI bootloader/manager for Linux.

Comment: @TomYan How can I do that? Do I have to install in my current Windows 7 disk? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if the board's (latest) UEFI supports booting from NVMe. If it doesn't, you can use the EFI system partition on the Windows/SATA drive instead, but `/boot` (i.e. the kernel and initramfs) will need to be on that drive as well.

Comment: Look for information on e.g. grub / systemd-boot installation on UEFI.